# Заменить несколько слов php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу заменить несколько слов в строке php

```
$my_str = "Привет, как дела?";
echo str_replace("Привет", "", "дела", "", $my_str);
```

Comment: Передавать первым параметром массив слов.

Comment: Передавать первым параметром массив слов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать прочитав более внимательно документацию, и узнать что параметры в `str_replace` имеют тип `mixed`, тем самым позволяя указывать не только строковые значения, но и массивы и т.д. Код для Вас ниже.

```
$my_str = "Привет, как дела?";
echo str_replace(["Привет","дела"], "", $my_str);
```

**UPD** Передайте массив и всё.

```
$my_str = "Привет, как дела?";
echo str_replace(["Привет","дела"], [1, 2], $my_str);
```

Comment: подскажите если привет нужно заменить на `1` а дела на `2`

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин дополнил ответ.